# Find a word of a file then remove the rest of the text of the file in PHP

Tags: php

Lets begin with an example. Say in a file file.php following texts exist.

```
This is just to show example. This is just to show example. This is just to show example. This is just to show example. end.  Okay This is just to show example. This is just to show example.
```

Now in the above text if i find okay then i will remove the rest of the content including the word okay and save the file in the server.

Someone please show me an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `explode` to split the content. Depending on how extensive your problem is this may not be the best solution, but I thought I would just include it also:

```
$string = $your_file_content
$split = explode('okay', strtolower($string));
//$split[0] = everything before 'okay';
//$split[1] = everything after 'okay';
```

Comment: if there were more than one instance of `okay` than this wouldn't work that well, the `$split` array would have more than 2 entries, and if there was no `okay`, there would be only 1 .... but as you said, it depends on the use case

Comment: @Landon exactly what I thought while I was writing it but thought I should still mention it.  Probably not the nicest solution but who knows, it could help the OP somewhere else down the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pos=strpos ($inputstring, 'okay');//test to see if there is a match (it will find the first match)
if($pos!==false){//if there was a match
   $cutstring=substr($inputstring, 0, $pos);//extract a substring from the begining to the match
   //echo $cutstring
}
```

Read more about those functions here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of different ways you can do this *strpos*, *regex*. Here's an example

```
$str = 'This is just to show example. This is just to show example. This is just to show example. This is just to show example. end.  Okay This is just to show example. This is just to show example.';

preg_match('%Okay%', $str, $match);

if($match){
  // save file to server 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "This is just to show example. This is just to show example. This is just to show  example. This is just to show example. end.  Okay This is just to show example. This is just to show example.";
$fnd = "Okay";
if (false !== $p = stripos($str, $fnd)) $str = substr($str, 0, $p);
echo $str; // Now save it or whatever.
```